# Where I can find the full Indesign Javascript Reference?

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign

Weirdly Adobe itself hasn't a browseable website where you can find all the Javascript Reference for it's programs, and you pay a lot for their softwares...

Some time ago, there was a full awesome website with all the Indesign Javascript reference, it was self hosted by a guy at http://jongware.com/idjshelp.html that website was very well made with reference for all the CS and CC versions of Adobe Indesign. The only drawback was that there wasn't a downloadable pdf or html version of that website, so now that the website is down there'snt a way to retrieve that data... :/

The only files that i've found from Adobe are super small, very lack and missing of info, nothing compared to the work of jongware that basically generated an auto documentation based on program api.

There's a website, maybe on a more stable platform like github where I can find the Adobe Indesign Javascript full documentation ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always access old websites (including that one) via the wayback machine. I'm not familiar with Adobe so I don't know if the information you're looking for is posted anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I tend to forget about the wayback archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full documentation is available on their developer site. Take a look at https://developer.adobe.com

I found the InDesign extend script reference here:
https://developer.adobe.com/console/servicesandapis/id

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the [InDesign ExtendScript API](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#about.html) by Gregor Fellenz.

(And yes, I agree, it's ridiculous that Adobe themselves do not manage to offer such a service. And Jongware sadly passed away a while ago, that's why his website is down now.)

Comment: I'm sorry to learn that :( the website he did was awesome.