InDesign doc to HTML doc conversion
Due to some reasons, we want to convert InDesign documents to responsive and accessible HTML. If we do manually, it would be very time consuming and costly as well. We want to automate or semi-automate this process. I explored browsing results and I am very confused if there is any solution or not? If there is any solution, what is the solution?
We tried to directly export in InDesign software, but spoiled the layout of our document.
I heard about UXP APIs, but I cannot find any reference for querying data from InDesign file. Is there any reference which I can refer to?
Is there any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821269/where-i-can-find-the-full-indesign-javascript-reference/73827597#73827597

Does this answer your question? Where I can find the full Indesign Javascript Reference?

You can try to export your layout into EPUB. Basically EPUB is the classic HTML within a zip-archive. Of course not any layout can be exported with no problem (pictures, tables, fancy font styles, etc). Probably you have to modify/simplify your layout first to prevent the troubles.
