insert AnchoredObject content in the parent textFrame at the right position
I'm trying to build an InDesign plugin using UXP to generate a clean HTML export of an InDesign file.
Currently, during the export process, anchored objects are exported as images. However, I want to extract their textual content instead. When I use releaseAnchoredObject, I can retrieve their content, but it is no longer correctly positioned within the content flow in terms of hierarchy.
I would like to try a different approach by extracting the content of the anchored object and inserting it at the anchored object insertion point, so it remains within the content flow.
However, I'm encountering two issues:
Sometimes, the contents property is empty, and I can't properly retrieve the content.
I can't find the correct insertion point.
I find the InDesign DOM documentation quite confusing. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should approach this?
Thank you!

If the DOM documentation isn't clear, you could try the Java Script reference mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821269/where-i-can-find-the-full-indesign-javascript-reference/73827597#73827597

I believe there is a proper solution, but as a work around you can try to release the anchored object, retrieve the content and undo the last step: app.undo().

Hello, Thanks for the response :)
This work around will not give me the insertion point where to insert the content :/
